# Why is that anonymous function declaration allowed but this one not?

Tags: scala

Why does this work:

```
val addOne = {a : Int => a + 1 }
```

But this not:

```
val addOne = a: Int => a + 1
```

As far as I understand, both declare an anonymous function with one input parameter.

Comment: Interestingly, `val addOne = (a : Int => a + 1 )` doesn't work either.

Comment: I suspect the compiler is trying to read it as, rather than a function that accepts an `Int` parameter, a function that accepts a *function* `(Int => ?)` parameter, and when it gets to trying to work out what the ? is it breaks as it is expecting a type literal rather than an expression.

Comment: @Russell This does not work, because jast a is the parameter. You are mixing the parameter with the body.

Answer (score 5):

Parameter list has to go in brackets.

```
val addOne = (a: Int) => a + 1
```

For full syntax, see the language spec.

Answer (score 4):

Because you define a function and assign it to a value.

```
{ a: Int => a + 1 }
```

Is a defined function. You can define the function this way as well:

```
(a: Int) => a + 1
```

or

```
(a: Int) => { a + 1 }
```

It is the same. You just have to wrap the parameterlist with brackets to make it work if you don't want to use paranthese surounding the hole expression.